# npm command not working in git bash terminal inside PhpStorm

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, git-bash

I have set the `Shell path` to the `sh.exe` in PhpStorm but i cannot run the npm command in the console. It says: `bash: npm: command not found` but I can run the command in the normal git bash console that I open outside of PhpStorm.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, I had to run PhpStorm with admin rights.